# How Do I get The Same Number In console.log?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

```js
let a = 15511210043330985984000000;
console.log(BigInt(a).toString());
```

How Do I get the Same a value.

Comment: `let a = BigInt(15511210043330985984000000); console.log(a.toString());`

Comment: or - `let a = 15511210043330985984000000n;` will work too

Comment: As `15511210043330985984000000`  is bigger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, you should use BigInt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Comment: No, It will not work. By the way Thanks For the quick response.

Comment: Which will not work? this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#BigInt_type

Comment: I am Using BigInt But It seems It rounding my value.

Comment: @ashutoshsarangi note that there is an `n` after Randy's number, it makes it a literal bigint

Comment: @StefanWang you would need to wrap the number literal in a string `BigInt("15511210043330985984000000");`

Comment: otherwise it is a number that is bigger than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER :-)

Comment: @NickParsons yeah, right. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to load as a string for this to work or append `n` at the end

`let a = BigInt('15511210043330985984000000');`

or

`let a = 15511210043330985984000000n;`

Comment: The `n` after the number makes it a bigint already, so your second version can just be `let a = 15511210043330985984000000n;`

Comment: Right. How did I miss it? Updating the answer.